# Xcode Line Wrapping setting doesn't work

Tags: xcode, word-wrap

I'm trying to disable line wrap in Xcode 4.3.2 (4E2002), but the setting doesn't seem to work. I seriously HATE line wrapping and it makes me super-unproductive. I've always had it turned off before, but since the latest XCode-update, it is enabled regardless of setting.

Is this an Xcode bug?

This is my settings dialog:
[image]

Comment: It must be a bug, I am still having the same problem 2 years later. I have seen it do this for a while now. Xcode 5.1.1

Comment: I can confirm that I'm also hitting this bug, even on XCode 6.1.  Annoying.

Answer (score 13):

This comes by some files you have set Wrap line in `Show the File inspector`.

Please choose a file. `View -> Utilities -> Show File inspector` then deselect Wrap lines in `Text Settings` section.

Answer (score 1):

I had >ONE< file out of two dozen that was wrapping it's text in the XCode editor.  Although I don't know how/why the file got into this state, I figured out what it was and how to fix it.

If you show the XCode right-hand Utilities pane, and select the Document icon at the top left, you'll see a variety of settings relevant to that one file, including it's name, type, and location.  Below that are some "Text Settings" values, including a checkbox for "Wrap lines".  If that box is checked, it overrides the XCode preference and wraps the lines.

This picture shows the XCode editor areas, in case you are confused:  [XCode Editor Areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0n9c.png)